# define is not defined jquery - ext-language_tools.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have this html page with these libraries:

```
...
<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.0/ace.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.0/ext-language_tools.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
...
```

When I load my page in the console I have the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined (jquery 1.12.4)

This problem si the library ext-language_tools.js that contains:

```
define("ace/snippets",["re....
```

What I can do to resolve the problem?

Comment: Are you using RequireJS?

Comment: i am not using it

Comment: The way you are attempting to import the extension is using RequireJs. I'm not seeing the built packages on a CDN, but they are provided on the ace website.